# How to adjust image in android screen under status bar and navigation in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

I am using an Imageview to show an image. If I set the image in background then its taking full widths and height under status bar and navigation bar. like as in below screen.
And the image is streching.

```
          <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLoginImageSlider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/slider2" />
```

[image]

In the second case if I set image using **Glide** then this same image not taking full widths and height. There is some space in top and bottom of the image. Like in below image.

```
Glide.with(context).load(model.getDrawable_img()).into(holder.binding.imgLoginImageSlider);
```

But I want to set the image using programmatically, How to do then. Any help? Thanks in advance. Image should not be streach.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Adding this property to the ImageView will fix your issue

`android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Learn more about this [here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide)

Comment: Thanks for comment. Still image is streching.